# Making a list with all dirs and files = ctime for each

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm pretty new to coding in general and have recently picked up python as my first programming language. As of right now my goal is to make a script that lists all the files and sub directories (and the ctimes of each) of a specified directory. I do have that list but I have trouble getting the ctime to work  correctly. if I try to put the files and sub directories in a function it says it can't take lists.
It does work with the root location for some reason.

Here is my code as of right now:

```
def my_function():
z = os.path.getctime(root)
c = os.path.getctime(dirs)
a = os.path.getctime(files)
time = datetime.fromtimestamp(z,c,a).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S {}")
     print(time)

import os
from datetime import datetime
os.getcwd()
os.chdir("U:/")
x = os.access("U:/verzeichnis xyz", os.F_OK)
if  x == True:
    print("Access to directory xyz = ", x)
    path = "U:/verzeichnis xyz"
    for (root,dirs,files) in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
        print(root)
        print(dirs)
        print(files)
        my_function()
        print("---------------")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

OUTPUT:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\python\test3.py in <module>
     25         print(dirs)
     26         print(files)
---> 27         my_function()
     28         print("---------------")
     29 else:

~\python\test3.py in my_function()
      8 def my_function():
      9     z = os.path.getctime(root)
---> 10     c = os.path.getctime(dirs)
     11     a = os.path.getctime(files)
     12     time = datetime.fromtimestamp(z,c,a).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S {}")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\genericpath.py in getctime(filename)
     63 def getctime(filename):
     64     """Return the metadata change time of a file, reported by os.stat()."""
---> 65     return os.stat(filename).st_ctime
     66
     67

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not list
```

P.S: I am using python 3.7 on Windows 10 Pro and verzeichnis xyz is my example directory
EDIT: 
How I would add the dirs and files and my output is listed above

Comment: What error/exception you are getting?

Comment: Im not directly getting an error with this code but when I add (dirs, files) to the function above it tells me that getctime wont take lists.

Comment: Then this is the relevant part for your question. Would you please show us the code how you call `my_function()` with lists of items? You say you "add" (dirs, files) to the function. We need to see how you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_function` needs to the root and the files from `os.walk`, then iterate over the elements of `files`.

E.g.:

```
def my_function(root, files):
    for file in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        z = os.path.getctime(path)    
        time = datetime.fromtimestamp(z).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        print("Timestamp of '%s' is %s" % (file, time))
```

Comment: Now I have the date the files were created, but what about the directories?

Comment: Just call `my_function(root, dirs)`. You can even call `my_function(root, dirs + files)`